# How to create this "Riser/Uplifter"

Tags: synthesizer

I came across this "Riser"/"Uplifter" which is frequently used in trap music.
But I don't really know how to create it.. All I can guess is that the sound has a volume envelope to it which has a fairly fast cycle of going up and down which itself speeds up over time, and then there's a rise in pitch, could be white noise with a bit resonance added to a wavetable in a synth but I'm not sure..
And I don't really have a clue what effects may be used, can you help me out with this sound?

Example 1: (1:00-1:05)

Example 2: (0:17-0:22)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

gradual pitch automation (a few bars) combined with lfo rate pitch and volume automation on some sort of widened saw or square wave should get you something resembling these kinds of sounds. You should be able to do it with any subtractive synth plugin... let me know if you require more explanation

as for post fx - its common in trap music to have a lot of reverb and automating the wet amount to rise gradually up and then dropping it all the way out after a transition. Tons of compression/distortion is also pretty common.